# JEdit settings and plugins

Tags: jedit

I would like to prepare a version of JEdit that my students could use right away, without having to install the necessary plugins and changing many settings. 
Is there a "clean" way of doing this, i.e. something that would be cross-platform and could be distributed publicly, not just to the students? 
This answer was of some help, but does not address the same need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36683022/6771080

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I effectively do this on every machine I use by copying the ~/.jedit  or c:/users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/jEdit folder. It includes the plugins and all the settings.

Comment: To clarify - the folder `C:\users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\jEdit` contains all the jEdit settings for Windows user `username`, and can be copied to the equivalent folder for another user (e.g. `C:\users\<otheruser>\AppData\Roaming\jEdit`) who will then have the same look-and-feel, plugins, and all settings exactly as per the first user. I've encountered minor issues where if the first user had selected a printer in the printer dialog that was not available to the second user the print dialog would never come up, but a minor tweak to the jEdit properties file fixes this. A good, free editor.